# Is there a way to load state using AsyncStorage through Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to load an array I saved using AsyncStorage back into state but I cant seem to get it working. I am passing the array from AsyncStorage back into context and calling the load_state case.

```
function loadList() {
    try {
        const data = AsyncStorage.getItem('data')
        console.log(data)
        loadState(JSON.parse(data))
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

const loadState = dispatch => {
return (value) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'load_state', payload: value})
}}

case 'load_state':
            console.log(action.payload.value)
            return [...state, ...action.payload.value]
```